# SwiftUI - Passing data from arrays into structs

Tags: swiftui

I'm having difficulties passing the data from the array into WeatherWidget that passes each item through WidgetView.
I believe it has something to do with how I declared `@State`.

// ContentView

```
struct WeatherWidget: View {

    @State var weather = weatherData
    @State var index = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
            TabView(selection: self.$index) {
                ForEach(weatherData) { weather in
                    WidgetView(data: weather)
                        // Identifies current index
                        .tag(self.index)
                }
            }
            .animation(.easeOut)
        }
        .animation(.easeOut)
    }
}
```

// Widget

```
struct WidgetView: View {

    @State var data: Weather
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(data.temp)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 24))
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding(.bottom, 16)
                Text(data.city)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.bottom, 4)
                Text(data.range)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            Image(systemName: data.icon)
                .font(.system(size: 32, weight: .medium))
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 185, height: 169)
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24, style: .continuous).fill(Color.black.opacity(0.8)))
    }
}
```

// Weather Struct

```
struct Weather : Hashable, Identifiable {

    var id = UUID()
    var temp : String
    var city : String
    var range : String
    var icon : String
}
```

// Data Array

```
var weatherData = [

    Weather(temp: "26°C", city: "Toronto, ON", range: "17°C / 28°C", icon: "sun.max"),
    Weather(temp: "17°C", city: "Waterloo, ON", range: "14°C / 24°C", icon: "cloud.rain"),
    Weather(temp: "31°C", city: "Whitby, ON", range: "24°C / 32°C", icon: "cloud.bolt.rain")
]
```

Comment: Where are you initializing your array (last code snippet). Where is that in?

Comment: Where's the weatherData declared, it's not on any of the structs you posted, and more importantly what's the error? Because the variable can be declared in another file and still being accessible from the WeatherWidget